# Power pivot ytd calculation

Tags: powerpivot

Ok, I have watched many videos and read all sorts and I think I am nearly there, but must be missing something. In the data model I am trying to add the `ytd` calc to my `product_table`. I don't have unique dates in the `product_table` in column `a` and also they are weekly dates. I have all data for 2018 for each week of this year in set rows of 20, incrementing by one week every 20 rows. E.g. rows 1-20 are 01/01/2018, rows 21-40 are 07/01/2018, and so on.

Whilst I say they are in set rows of 20, this is an example. Some weeks there are more or less than 20 so I can't use the row count function-

Between columns `c` and `h` I have a bunch of other categories such as customer age, country etc. so there isn't a unique identifier. Do I need one for this to work? Column `i` is the sales column with the numbers. What I would like is a new column which gives me a `ytd` number for each row of data which all has unique criteria between `a` and `h`. Week 1 `ytd` is not going to be any different. For the next 20 rows I want it to add week1 sales to week2 sales, effectively giving me the `ytd`.

I could sumproduct this easily in the data set but I don't want do that. I want to use dax to save space etc..

I have a `date_table` which does have unique dates in the `main_date` column. All my date columns are formatted as date in the data model.

I have tried:

```
=calculate(products[sales],datesytd(date_table[main_date]))
```

This simply replicates the numbers in the sales column, not giving me an `ytd` as required. I also tried

```
=calculate(sum(products[sales]) ,datesytd(date_table[main_date]))
```

I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible. All the youtube clips don't seem to have the same issues I am having but I think they have unique dates in their data sets.

Id love to upload the data but its work stuff on a work computer so cant really. Hope I've painted the picture quite clearly.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example of how your data looks and what you want to transform it to?

Comment: I havent been posting long enough to upload an image. If u can imagine, column a has week commencing date, column b has the year number. C to h has country, age etc then i has sales amount. In laymans terms, with a sumproduct i would say, sum everything in the sales column where the date is less than or equal to the we date, the year is 2018 and the criteria matches all of my other columns. I need to replicate this sort of formula in dax. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, after googling sumif dax, mike honey had a response that i have adapted to get what i need. I needed to add the filter and earlier functions to my equarion and it ended up like this

```
Calculate (sum(products[sales]), 
filter (sales, sales[we_date] <=earlier(sales[we_date]), 
filter (sales, sales[year] =earlier(sales[year]),
filter (sales, sales[customer] =earlier(sales[customer]))
```

There are three other filter sections i had to add, but this now gives me the ytd i needed.

Hope this helps anyone else